# Check a file path belong to folder name

Tags: c#, .net, file, io

I want to check a folder name is contain a file path or not.
e.g.

```
string filePath = @"C:/vietnam/hello/world/welcome.jpg"
IsFileBelongToFolderName(filePath, "hello");//should return true
IsFileBelongToFolderName(filePath, "hell");//should return false
```

In simple case, I just check the file path contain "/FolderName/", but am not sure it is correct for any case

Do have any build-in function for this check ?

**UPDATE**
In real example, we are create application to synchronize folder. Some sub folder contain meta file, so we don't want to sync it.

Instead pass simple folder name, we want to pass chain of sub folders, e.g: `folderName = "hello/world"`. I think it less complex but work same meaning with `.gitignore` file. 
For now:

```
string filePath = @"C:/vietnam/hello/world/welcome.jpg"
IsFileBelongToFolderName(filePath, "hello/world");//should return true
IsFileBelongToFolderName(filePath, "hell/world");//should return false
IsFileBelongToFolderName(filePath, "hell");//should return false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this by splitting `filepath` using `DirectorySeparatorChar`

```
var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath);

filePath = Path.GetFullPath(directorypath); // Get Canonical  directory path (Credit to @Aron for pointing this.) 
bool exist = filePath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
                     .Any(x=>x.Equal("hello", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: You should canonicalization the paths first. For example `c:\foo\bar\baz.txt` belongs to `c:\foo\bar\qux\..\`.

Comment: You should exclude the file name first, it will not work if folderName = "welcome.jpg"

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool IsFileBelongToFolderName(string filePath, string folderName)
{
    return filePath.Split('/').Contains(folderName);;
}
```

or

```
public bool IsFileBelongToFolderName(string filePath, string folderName)
{
     return filePath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Any(x=>x.Equal(folderName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string filePath = @"C:/vietnam/hello/world/welcome.jpg";
            string[] folderNames = filePath.Split('/');
            if(folderNames.Contains("hello"))
            {
                   //folder found
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public bool IsFileBelongToFolderName(string filePath, string name){
    return filePath.ToLower().Contains(@"/"+name.ToLower().Replace(@"/", "")+@"/");
}


string filePath = @"C:/vietnam/hello/world/welcome.jpg";

IsFileBelongToFolderName(filePath,"vietnam"); // return True
IsFileBelongToFolderName(filePath,"Vietnam"); // return True
IsFileBelongToFolderName(filePath,"Vietna"); // return false
IsFileBelongToFolderName(filePath,"welcome.jpg"); // return false
```